# How to prevent fabric form waiting for the process to return

Tags: python, fabric

I always use fabric to deploy my processes from my local pc to remote servers.

If I have a python script like this:

test.py:

```
import time
while True:
    print "Hello world."
    time.sleep(1)
```

Obviously, this script is a continuous running script.
And I deploy this script to remote server and execute my fabric script like this:

```
...
sudo("python test.py")
```

The fabric will always wait the return of test.py and won't exit.How can I stop the fabric script at once and ignore the return of test.py

Comment: That's kinda the point of `Fabric`: running tasks and reporting their status. Why do you want this? If you run tasks on multiple machines, `Fabric` will ran them in parallel, so this feature seems useless…

Comment: sudo("python test.py&")

Comment: If you want to start some service, that's not the way to go. [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) is one way to set this up. init-scripts, upstart are others, depending on your linux distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo("python test.py  2>/dev/null >/dev/null &")`

or redirect the output to some other file instead of /dev/null

Answer (score 3):

Usually for this kind of asynchronous task processing [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) is preferred .
[This](http://nicholaskuechler.com/2012/06/19/auto-scale-rackspace-cloud-servers-with-fabric-and-celery/) explains in detail the use of Celery and Fabric together.

```
from fabric.api import hosts, env, execute,run
from celery import task

env.skip_bad_hosts = True
env.warn_only = True

@task()
def my_celery_task(testhost):
    host_string = "%s@%s" % (testhost.SSH_user_name, testhost.IP)

    @hosts(host_string)
    def my_fab_task():
        env.password = testhost.SSH_password
        run("ls")

    try:
        result = execute(my_fab_task)
        if isinstance(result.get(host_string, None), BaseException):
            raise result.get(host_string)
    except Exception as e:
        print "my_celery_task -- %s" % e.message
```

Comment: Blog post is dead, but his GitHub repo has some the scripts: https://github.com/nicholaskuechler/autoscale-rackspacecloud-fabric-celery

Comment: This approach is not executing the task on the nodes in parallel. Rather it running it as serial execution as fabric normally does.

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me:

```
fabricObj.execute("(nohup python your_file.py > /dev/null < /dev/null &)&")
```

Where `fabricObj` is an object to fabric class(defined internally) which speaks to fabric code.